# React Native navigation web linking

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation, react-native-web, expo-linking

I developped a big app with React native with expo on Android & iOS and all works fine.
Then i had to convert it in a web project.

URL linking work in expo (localhost:19006) but **not in production**.

The web compiled version is hosted on a NGinx.

**Packages in question:**

```
"expo": "^41.0.0",
"expo-linking": "~2.2.3",
"@react-navigation/native": "^5.7.4"
```

**I have two navigations:**

- LoginNavigation
- SignedNavigation

**My linking is something like**

```
const config = {
    screens: {
        login: ["login", "*"],
        register: "register",
        register2Mail: "registerConfirm"
    },
  };
  
  const prefix = Linking.createURL('https://urlofwebsite/');
  
  const linking = {
    prefixes: [prefix],
    config,
  };
```

When i navigate through the app with navigation prop, all works fine and url is updated.

**Example: mysite.com/history**

**But** if i reload the page or copy paste an url, i fallback to **404 not found** everytime.

Is this a know issue ? I can't find any similar case.